"url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid
I am using remotive api( https://remotive.com/api/remote-jobs) for next js project.In this api there is  a URL to the company logo.
i am using it like this
<Image
                src={'https://remotive.com/job/1912073/logo'}
                className="w-6 aspect-square"
                alt=""
                width={18}
                height={18}
              />

and in config file
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'remotive.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/job/**', // Matches any path under /job/
      },
    ],
  },
  };
  
  export default nextConfig;
  

but getting error..
⨯ upstream image response failed for https://remotive.com/job/1912073/logo 403..
i am using  "next": "^14.2.3",
"react": "^18.3.1"
Any solution.
I searched many website but did not get any solution

This url first takes to a security validation by cloudflare. Thats the reason its returning 403. Check with any other image link where host does not require any validation.
